# Prefer matching search text in beginning of result using elasticsearch in ElasticSearch Match Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a query and sometimes I can't get to return the most relevant answer:

```
GET /items2/_search
{
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "description": {
            "query": "query_value",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO:3,3",
            "max_expansions": 10,
            "prefix_length": 0
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I want to return firstly `query_value another_value` then `another_value query_value`.
I know about `span_first`, but for the text field for fuzzy search, this is not suitable.

How I can do this in Match Query?

Comment: You tried combine match query, prefix or match phrase?

Comment: @rabbitbr, Thank you for response! I tried them all separately, all of them returns same results and equal scores. So, I think the combination will not give anything